# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Mono<A> to Mono<B>

Tags: project-reactor

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Mono to Mono. Wants to add error messge to B then i wants to return Mono of B.

```
public  Mono<B> case1(){
    A a = new A();
    a.setName("srihari");
    B b = new B();
    a.setName("G SRIHARI");
    Mono<A> mono = Mono.error(new RuntimeException("HARISRI"));

    return mono.onErrorResume(d->{
         b.setErrorMessage(d.getMessage());
        return Mono.just(b);
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [signature](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.util.function.Function-) of `onErrorResume()`, the fallback function can only result in a Mono of the same type as the source Mono. This is for good reason.

What if you instead had `Mono<A> mono = Mono.just(new A());`. Now, no error will be thrown, so the fallback function will never be invoked. Therefore, you still have a `Mono<A>`, *not* a `Mono<B>`.

This isn't really anything special with Reactor. Consider the same kind of flow with a try catch:

```java
public B foo() {
  try {
    // throw new RuntimeException();
    return new A();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return new B();
  }
}
```

Obviously, this code does not compile because if an error is not thrown, `A` will be returned, but the method must return `B`. This is essentially what you are trying to write but with Reactor.

Comment: What can we use instead of this onErrorResume(-). Please suggest me

Comment: @GSriHAri you need to reconsider the code you're trying to write. I've edited my answer explaining why this cannot work (there is no operator to accomplish this).

Comment: This was a good explanation - In my case, I had three return statements and sussed out which one was the issue by assigning to a single return variable of the expected type.